# How do you get the current time of day in datetime format?

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

How do I get the current time of day in datetime format?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [DateTime.TimeOfDay](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday.aspx):

```
TimeSpan currentTime = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
```

This will retrieve this as a TimeSpan.  If you want this in a "DateTime" format, just use `DateTime.Now` (realizing, of course, that this also includes the date).

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DateTime.Now](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.now.aspx) for that. Example:

```
$ cat Test.cs
using System;

namespace Test
{
   public class TestClass
   {
      public static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         DateTime example = DateTime.Now;
         Console.WriteLine(example);
      }
   }
}

$ gmcs *.cs
$ mono Test.exe
2/18/2011 11:03:13 PM
```